# Docker build MySQL dockerfile occur none:none

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i just download the MySQL [dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/77f0a50ecd54edafe48ce3a2a328c22e9e7564a8/5.7/Dockerfile). And run this command

```
docker build -t helloworld:1.0.0 .
```

and then run

```
docker images

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              491aa62016dd        21 hours ago        384.5 MB
centos              7                   970633036444        7 days ago          196.7 MB
debian              jessie              1b01529cc499        8 days ago          125.1 MB
```

i found that a image with none:none is generated. The repository is none. Tag is none.

Anyone know the issue?

Comment: Was the build of your image succesful? Can your past the last lines of the output of your build command? I would think that the image-build failed and that you see the 'intermediate image'. These images are the intermediate steps used for the build cache. So when you will retry to rebuild the image it will go a lot faster because it will use the cache.

Comment: @lorenzvth7 thx. i found the issue. You are right that the image-build fail. i missed to download the docker-entrypoint.sh, which the dockerfile requires it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found the issue. Missed to download the docker-entrypoint.sh, which the MySQL dockerfile requires it

Also, need to run

```
chmod 777 docker-entrypoint.sh
```

to grant permission